# Cannot modify body of intercepted Reply event in Outlook 2016

Tags: vba, outlook

I am creating a macro which, whenever user clicks "Reply" button to reply to e-mail, intercepts reply event and modifies BCC/subject/body of the reply.

BCC and subject are being modified, but body does not want to change.

Here is macro I am using:

```
Private WithEvents oExpl As Explorer
Private WithEvents oItem As mailItem
Private bDiscardEvents As Boolean

Private Sub Application_Startup()
  Set oExpl = Application.ActiveExplorer
  bDiscardEvents = False
End Sub

Private Sub oExpl_SelectionChange()
  On Error Resume Next
  Set oItem = oExpl.Selection.Item(1)
End Sub

Private Sub oItem_Reply(ByVal Response As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim responseItem As mailItem
    Set responseItem = Response

    ' Both work fine
    responseItem.BCC = "example@example.com"
    responseItem.Subject = "this is reply subject"

    ' None of them works
    responseItem.HTMLBody = "this is reply html body"
    responseItem.Body = "this is reply text body"
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Display it before you can edit...

Example

```
    ' None of them works
'    responseItem.HTMLBody = "this is reply html body"
    responseItem.display
    responseItem.body = "this is reply text body" & responseItem.body
```

Comment: This worked for me.  Not sure why it was not marked as the answer!  Thanks for the helpful reply and example.